# How to call jQuery code after Backbone template is rendered?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events

I am building an app with Backbone.js (using Underscore templates), Express and Node.js.

I made this very simple example to illustrate the problem (see code below), the app consists in a list of "titles" retrieved from the server.

I use an underscore template to render the HTML. After the HTML is rendered I would like to execute some jQuery code, like for example print in the console the position() of each "title". **The problem is that the jQuery code gets called before the template has inserted the elements in the DOM, so jQuery can't find the elements.**

What am I missing? **Is there a way to get an event after the html is inserted in the DOM?**

Here the code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="tracks">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Template -->
    <script id="trackTemplate" type="text/template">

        <ul id="<%= id2 %>" style="height:150px">
            <li><%= title %></li> 
        </ul>               

        <%
        // So it looks like this code gets code before the template's HTML is in the DOM.
            console.log($("#"+id2).position());
        %>
    </script>

    <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = app || {};

    // Model
    app.Track = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id2: '',
            title: 'Track',
        },
    });

    // Collection
    app.Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Track,
        url: '/api/tracks' 
    });

    // Track view
    app.TrackView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'trackContainer',
        template: _.template( $( '#trackTemplate' ).html() ),
        initialize:function(){
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

            return this;
        },

    });

    // Collection View
    var numberOfTracks = 0;
    app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#tracks',

        initialize: function( initialTracks ) {
            this.collection = new app.Library( initialTracks );
            this.collection.fetch(); 
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderTrack);
        },

        // render library by rendering each track in its collection
        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(function( item ) {
                this.renderTrack( item );
                numberOfTracks++;
            }, this );
        },

        // render a track by creating a trackView and appending the
        // element it renders to the library's element
        renderTrack: function( item ) {
            var trackView = new app.TrackView({
                model: item
            });
            this.$el.append( trackView.render().el );
        },
    });

    // Initialise app
    var libraryView =  new app.LibraryView();
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To cover some ground here, there isn't an event that fires once something is inserted into the DOM. I wouldn't actually advocate trying to get around that by putting code inside your template either. Rather take a look at the way your views are rendering.

If you want to throw some code into a pre-existing place holder you could look at doing something like this:

```
[view here].setElement(this.$([selector here])).render();
```

There's an excellent explanation of this at:

http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/

It's a neat way of arranging sub-views if you don't need any heavyweight sub-view management. You should after that point be able to do stuff with jquery as your normally would within a view using this.$el and this.$. Providing your element is correctly scoped within the view.

Answer (score 0):

- The right place for your `console.log` call would be at the end of your `render` method or in `renderTrack`, right after `append`.
- Backbone also makes it easy to create your own events and sign up for them through [Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events). You could fire your own event at one of the places I mentioned in the previous paragraph.
- There is a deprecated event family for tracking changes in the DOM called [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) - but they are deprecated and browser support is not quite reliable. The replacement is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), defined in the [DOM4 spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers), browser support is not there yet (IE only has support from 11) but for testing it might be useful.
- Another way would be to put your code in a `setTimeout` - this way the DOM node will surely be inserted at the time your `console.log` runs.

Comment: I tried to put the `console.log` at the end of the `render` method but didn't solve the problem. I can fire an event as you say, however the problem I have is that the is some time between the template rendering (which could fire an event) and the insertion of the HTML elements in the DOM. What I need is and event when the HTML is in the DOM. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @andreugrimalt Where are you putting it exactly and exactly what code are you putting there? What is the result? The element should be inserted to the DOM right after `append`/`html` is called.

Comment: The result is something like this: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'postion'`. This means that the element doesn't exist... Actually `$("#"+id2).length` returns 0. I agree that the element should be inserted to the DOM right after `append` is called. Unfortunately it's not the case...

Comment: @andreugrimalt I'm not sure about that. First, I'm curious what is in the `id2` variable - I guess it is `undefined`. Second, `postion` is not the same as `position`. My theory is that the element is inserted, the problem is the way you are trying to track it.

Comment: The model has a property called `id2` so you can access it from the template and it's not undefined. `postion` is indeed not what I tried to mean :) just edited the question. The elements get indeed inserted but with a bit of delay (like in an asynchronous way). I know this happens because if I set a setTimeout and I keep calling `$("#"+id2).position()` I get a non undefined position after a few milliseconds.

Comment: @andreugrimalt Hard to say more without being able to tinker with a demo.

Comment: I agree that a demo would be good but not possible at the moment. I am trying to figure out if this behaviour (javascript code called before template inserting html in DOM) is to be expected or not.

Comment: Just a suggestion off the top of my head. It could be down to how _.template works (using with). Maybe try using the following syntax: _.template(tmpl, {data here}, {'variable': 'data'});